# Fragment Shader Eye-Space unscaled depth coordinate

Tags: opengl, glsl, fragment-shader

I'm trying to use the unscaled (true distance from the front clipping plane) distance to objects in my scene in a GLSL fragment shader.  The gl_FragCoord.z value is smaller than I expect.  In my vertex shader, I just use ftransform() to set gl_Position.  I'm seeing values between 2 and 3 when I expect them to be between 15 and 20.

How can I get the real eye-space depth?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass whatever you want down as a varying from the vertex shader.

the Z value available in the fragment shader has gone through normalization based on your z-near/z-far (from the projection matrix), and DepthRange. So it is not directly what you're after. Technically, you could try to reconstruct it by reverting the various OpenGL operations on Z that happen after the vertex shader, but it's probably more trouble (starting with the fact that reverting the projection matrix is non-linear) than just passing down what you want, exactly.

As a side note, the Z you would compute with `gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex` is the Z from the point of view, not the near-Z plane.

Comment: Awesome, I just passed `-(gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex).z` as a varying float and that's just what I needed